# XPage Slowness when agent runs

Tags: xpages

I have seen some strange XPage slowness in a database that have a long running export agent.
I you fire the export agent all xpages starts to got slow in the application. If I look at the server the agent manager is using 25% CPU so it's plenty of CPU power left. I don't have any agent that runs from the XPages. 
Anybody else seeing this?
It there a way to prevent this from happening ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause could be one of many. You'll need to start to diagnose what is happening to discover where the contention is occurring. For example, if you are reading/writing a lot of documents then depending on your disk configuration there could be contention in the disk subsystem. Alternatively, if your memory is too low, you may be causing a lot of garbage collection to happen in the JVM, which can also cause slowness.

I would start with the XPages Toolbox to see if you can determine where the slowdown occurs and investigate from there. If you need to look deeper, look at yourkit java profiler (http://www.yourkit.com) which will give you a plethora of information to help identify the source.

Answer (score 1):

... and perhaps you should try to profile your agent to see if there are any obvious places in the code that you could improve in terms of performance. Concurrent access to the same data could give bad response times (especially if one is write-access which could force view rebuilds). Try to open an XPage in the database that do not access the same data as the export agent - still slow?

To profile the agent you open it in the Designer and on the Basics tab of the properties you can enable "Profile this agent" :-)

/John